# How to fix Error : KeyError at /input 'Company'? When Selecting single Row From Dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

```
def input(request):
    if 'pass' in request.POST:
        company = request.POST['pass']
    else:
        company = False
    df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv',index_col = None)
    take = df.groupby('Company').mean()
    table = take[take['Company'] == company]
    table_content = table.to_html(classes = 'table')
    return render(request,'result.html',{'table_content': table_content})
```

I want to Represent Single Row In HTML In Tabular Form. But getting Error KeyError at /input
'Company'. 
Am working With Django.

KeyError at /input
'Company'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dictionary in python and you want to check if a key/value pair exists you should use `get`.  See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get

So this is what you should do in your web app as well.

Example:

```
d = {'k':'v'}
val = d.get('k')
if val is None:
  print('not found')
else:
  print('found')
```

Comment: It is Showing Error in This Line---->  table = take[take['Company'] == company]

Comment: so you need to logic like `company = take.get('Company')`, only if `company` is not `None` do your logic. The current expression ` table = take[take['Company'] == company]` is looking twice in take. 1) looking for 'compamy' 2) looking for True Or False that returns from the expression `take['Company'] == company`. are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yes! Am sure now, after printing company, it is showing valid name that exists in my CSV, I want to Print Single Row Which user wants to see. I have 'Company' as column name in CSV.

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html  The call to mean resturn a Serious that has no key named 'Company'